# How do I determine if an address is inside some boundaries on a map?

Tags: google-maps, gis, geocoding

I am doing some initial research this and I know very little about the subject.  I need to create a solution that can take an address and then determine if that address is within some predefined boundaries (probably a series of connected streets).  Does anybody have some advice on where to get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to geocode the address (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/), then you can use my point in polygon library to check if it is in the bounds. Check it out here: http://blog.appdelegateinc.com/point-in-polygon-checking-with-google-maps.html

*Update:* Check out the comments for someone who updated it to work with v3.

Comment: That is great, I can't think of a better way to get introduced.

Comment: Sorry. Switched to Amazon Cloudfront/S3 a while back. Updated.