# R: How to reverse geocode lat/lon into boroughs efficiently

Tags: r, mapping, gis, geocoding

I would like to find a solution to the same problem presented in this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984044/how-to-reverse-geocode-lat-lon-into-boroughs-efficiently) 
I quote the part that interests me:

> I am working with the New York City taxi data set. The data set has columns including datetime, pickup lat/lon, dropoff lat/lon etc. Now I want to reverse geocode the lat/lon to find the borough/neighborhood

My dataset has a few million rows so I need a computationally efficient method.
I downloaded this [file](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Neighborhood-Names-GIS/99bc-9p23). It contains neighborhood names and their centroids. I would like to use the same method as this answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736995/how-can-i-quickly-estimate-the-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points) to find the neighborhood whose centroid was the closest and then classified the data point to that neighborhood.

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    # Radius of earth in kilometers is 6371
    km = 6371* c
    return km
```

The problem is that I would like to use the same method but with R. Alternatively find another equally efficient method.

DATASET -> [Download 1,8 Gb](https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/yellow_tripdata_2015-01.csv)

Comment: A couple of suggestions, first there is the geosphere package useful for performing the distance calculations.  As far a computationally efficient method, then consider applying a divide and conquer strategy.  There is no reason to compute the distances for taxis on Staten Island to neighborhoods in Brooklyn and Queens.

Comment: Maybe this is just for your own learning, but I thought the NYC taxi data has the borough level pickup/dropoff location for each taxi ride?

Comment: Do you know https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic?

Comment: It would be helpful if you create a much smaller subset of the data, so folks don't need to download 1.8 gigs worth